# Why doesn't the fallback mechanism work here?

Tags: ruby

When accessing a variable, the fallback mechanism in Ruby first looks up local variables, and if it doesn't find one, it automatically applies `self` and looks up instance variables. However, the following code does not work:

```
class My
  def init
    @abc = "abc"
  end

  def pt
    puts abc
  end
end
```

I got this error message when I'm trying to call `pt` on an instance:

```
2.0.0-p247 :009 > my = My.new
 => #<My:0x007f9b5a1b1000> 
2.0.0-p247 :010 > my.init
 => "abc" 
2.0.0-p247 :011 > my.pt
NameError: undefined local variable or method `abc' for #<My:0x007f9b5a1b1000 @abc="abc">
```

However, `@abc` DOES exist as an instance variable in the object:

```
2.0.0-p247 :012 > my.instance_variables
=> [:@abc]
```

So why can't `pt` find `abc` here? Shouldn't it automatically look-up instance variables, since it's not defined locally, and print it?

NOTE:

I know using `puts @abc` would work, but this is NOT the point of my question. My question is about the fallback mechanism in Ruby. This code works:

```
2.0.0-p247 :079 > class My
2.0.0-p247 :080?>     def initialize(param)
2.0.0-p247 :081?>         @abc = param
2.0.0-p247 :082?>       end
2.0.0-p247 :083?>   
2.0.0-p247 :084 >       def printabc
2.0.0-p247 :085?>         puts abc
2.0.0-p247 :086?>       end
2.0.0-p247 :087?>   end

2.0.0-p247 :089 > My.new("haha").printabc
haha
```

I don't know why it doesn't work in the previous case but works in the latter.

Comment: Your second example will also throw error..

Comment: Your second example would throw an error too.

Comment: Given the line number, I suspect the reason it works is that `abc` has been defined higher up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do as below(you missed `@` symbol)

```
def pt
    puts @abc
end
```

> So why pt cannot find abc here?

What you are expecting, will happen, when you will be using `attr_accessor` or `attr_reader`. See below for the same. In this case,ruby will first check if there is any local variable is created with the name as `abc`, but when it doesn't find it,checks if there is a method is defined with name `abc`,by passing the message `abc` to `self`(`self.abc`). Now `attr_reader` defines a method `def abc; @abc ;end` (which is also one of the 2 methods of `attr_accessor`). Thus no error,you got the output of `@abc`.

```
class My
  attr_accessor :abc
  def init
    @abc = "abc"
  end

  def pt
    puts abc
  end
end

my = My.new
my.init # => "abc"
my.pt
# >> abc
```

Remember when there is a bare call like `foo` only,Ruby will always first check if it is local variable or not. If no local variable is found having name `foo` in the scope where it is found, then it checks if it is a method. See below one demo example to realize the fact :

```
x = 10
def x ;11;end
x # => 10
```

Comment: Certainly I know it would work with an `@` symbol. But I'm testing the FALLBACK mechanism, which looks up local var `abc` first and if not find it applies `self.abc`.

Comment: Or perhaps the OP is expecting behaviour of `attr_reader :abc` and has forgotten to use it.

Comment: @OneZero: There is no such thing as a "fallback mechanism" in Ruby for finding instance variables. You can however define a method `abc` and have that return the value. And in fact that is such a common thing that `attr_reader :abc` and `attr_accessor :abc` will do that for you, and so will many gems that allow you to build database classes etc.

Comment: But see my second example without attr_accessor or attr_reader. It still prints. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: If you are still in that session, what happens if you just enter `abc` on its own and press return? (I suspect you have defined `abc` globally whilst investigating the issue)

Comment: Or possibly you have opened the class multiple times and defined the method already. What does `My.instance_methods` return?

Comment: Arup, was a little surprised to see your answer checkmarked after reading the asker's comment. :-)